# Jquery&Ruby on Rails- can't get params although it is passed (using Ajax)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to pass a variable from jquery to rails controller.

These are my codes.

**Index.html.erb**

```
<a href="/cpu/test" id="ajaxclick" data-mess="show me">Ajax Link</a>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#ajaxclick").click(function(){
      var middle = $(this).data('mess')
    $.ajax({
               data: {
                   please: middle          },
               method: "POST",
                url: "/cpu/test",
                success: function(){
                  // $('#ajaxclick').append(fromcont);
                    alert(middle);

                }
           });
  });
  });
</script>
```

**cpu_controller.rb**

```
 def index
      @ajaxvar = (params[:please])
  end
  def test
      @ajaxvar = params[:please]
  end
```

**test.html.erb**

```
<%= @ajaxvar %>
```

My console says   `Parameters: {"please"=>"show me"}` but `@ajaxvar = params[:please]` is nil.

I also tried `data: { 'please=' + middle }` but it doesn't even pass the parameter `please`.

In case my routes is needed,

**routes.rb**

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'talking/index'
  get 'talking/eachnotice'
  get 'talking/edit'
  get 'talking/new'

  resources :meetings
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

  root 'cpu#index'

  resources :talks

  post ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
  get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
  get 'all' => 'talks#all'
  get 'mytalks' => 'talks#mytalks'
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't find any value in test.html.erb . You can find @ajaxvar in test.js.erb file. or if you don't want js.erb file then you have to send respond from action and have to receive in ajax success.
create a file named test.js.erb will be great for you.
in test.js.erb

```
  <%= raise @ajaxvar.inspect %>
```

and you will find your data in terminal